# Conditionally Formatting in R based on starting with text

Tags: r, xml, conditional-statements

I have the following code

```
library('XML')
url <- 'http://www.citact.org/politics-and-money-voting-records-and-
campaign-contributions/2016-indiana-general-assembly/news/2016-voting-
records'
small_url <- 'http://www.citact.org'
links_function <- function(url) 
{
  getLinks <- function() {
    links <- character()
    list(a = function(node, ...) {
      links <<- c(links, xmlGetAttr(node, "href"))
      node
    },
    links = function() links)
  }
  h1 <- getLinks()
  htmlTreeParse(url, handlers = h1)
  h1$links()
}
links <- links_function(url)
```

Some of these links come across missing the beginning to the link(what I have called small_url). I was wondering if there is a way to paste small_url onto the links that do not have them. I thought this could be done using a conditional statement, but I haven't figured out how to create a conditional based upon starting with certain text.

Comment: `links <- replace(links, substr(links, 1, 21) != small_url, paste0(small_url, links))` - perhaps with an added `/` depending on how the links are coming out.

Comment: That worked for pasting the links, but it still paste them even if they already contain small_url

Comment: This might be better... `links <- ifelse(substr(links, 1, 1) == "/", paste0(small_url, links), links)`

Comment: That worked. Thank you!